# My Python program compiles long enough to take input, but won't process the input

Tags: python

```
def funcName():
```

Storing inputs for the user's favourite subjects.

```
    in0 = input("Type your first favourite subject.")
    in1 = input("Type your second favourite subject.")
    in2 = input("Type your third favourite subject.")

    favSubjects = ['Physics', 'Computer_Science', 'Lunch']
```

Creating list of user's favourite subjects.

```
    favSubjects2 = []
```

Storing user's favourite subjects.

```
    favSubjects2[0] = in0
    favSubjects2[1] = in1
    favSubjects2[2] = in2
```

Comparing program's subjects with the user's.

```
    if(favSubjects[0] == favSubjects2[0] or favSubjects[0] == favSubjects2[1] or favSubjects[0] == favSubjects2[2]):
        print("Same!")
    elif(favSubjects[1] == favSubjects2[0] or favSubjects[1] == favSubjects2[1] or favSubjects[1] == favSubjects2[2]):
        print("Same!")
    elif(favSubjects[2] == favSubjects2[0] or favSubjects[2] == favSubjects2[1] or favSubjects[2] == favSubjects2[2]):
        print("Same!")

def main():
    funcName()

main()
```

Comment: `favSubjects2 = [in0, in1, in2]`; you can't assign to indices that don't already exist. I don't know if that will fix your observed problem, because you haven't said what your problem actually is.

Comment: Compiling is the step where [the interpreter converts python code into bytecode](http://effbot.org/zone/python-compile.htm).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will produce an `IndexError` as you cannot assign to indices that do not yet exist

```
favSubjects2 = []
favSubjects2[0] = in0
favSubjects2[1] = in1
favSubjects2[2] = in2
```

To store these items in your list you should use the following

```
favSubjects2 = [in0, in1, in2]
```